# Shortening words based on database in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to replace words in a cell with shorter versions in mass. I have a dictionary of words to make shorter and will have a column of cells that need to have one or more of the words shortened.

I am very new to VBA and I'm not sure how I would go about this. I tried searching and found some that would be changing text in a word doc but nothing from Excel to excel, at least with my search terms.

I have added a picture here of the Idea, the Text to be shortened is in column A, the words that can be shortened are in column C and the shortened versions are in column D.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4149M.jpg)

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the .Find function. This page has an example where the vba searches through a range for a value, then assigns a new value to that cell: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full sub version if that works better for you

```
Sub ReplaceViaList()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim repRng As Range
Dim x As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim repCol As Long, oldCol As Long, newCol As Long
Dim oldStr As String, newStr As String

'screenupdating/calc
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'define worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'define columns to work with
repCol = 1 'col A
oldCol = 3 'col C
newCol = 4 'col D

'find last row of replacement terms
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, repCol).End(xlUp).Row

'set range of items to be replaced
Set repRng = ws.Range( _
    ws.Cells(2, repCol), _
    ws.Cells(lastRow, repCol) _
    )

'loop through cells in replacement terms
For x = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, oldCol).End(xlUp).Row

    'define replacement terms
    oldStr = ws.Cells(x, oldCol).Value
    newStr = ws.Cells(x, newCol).Value

    'replace
    repRng.Replace What:=oldStr, Replacement:=newStr

Next x

'screenupdating/calc
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Even worked on the first try also. Thank you for the comments also, it will help me understand better what is happening and to learn from it!

Comment: Happy to help! If you're satisfied with the answer, consider 'Accepting' it to help others with the same question find it as well: see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this UDF.

```
Function SubstituteMultiple(text As String, old_text As Range, new_text As Range)
Dim i As Single
For i = 1 To old_text.Cells.Count
Result = Replace(LCase(text), LCase(old_text.Cells(i)), LCase(new_text.Cells(i)))
text = Result
Next i
SubstituteMultiple = Result
End Function
```

Place this code in your regular module. then write this formula `=SubstituteMultiple(A2,$C$2:$C$11,$D$2:$D$11)` in cell `B2` and drag it to the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps simple replace in VBA would do it,

```
Sub test()
    Dim searchval As Variant
    Dim replaceval As Variant

    searchval = Range("C1:C10")
    replaceval = Range("D1:D10")

    For i = 1 To 10
        Columns("A:A").Replace What:=searchval(i, 1), Replacement:=replaceval(i, 1), LookAt:=xlPart
    Next i
End Sub
```